# Applying And Condition on Elastic Search Document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing some issue with elastic search query. I've a data which looks like **array inside array**. When I'm applying the "AND" condition  on inner array it is retuning wrong result.

My Document structure looks like below

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "array1": [
    {
      "headline": "test",
      "description": "Test",
      "solutions": [
        "ABC",
        "XYZ",
        "EFG"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Every document has the array1 and solutions in it. I want to get the documents where **array1.solutions** match the **ABC** and **EFG**

My Query looks like below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"array1.solutions.keyword": "ABC"}},
        {"match": {"array1.solutions.keyword": "EFG"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If any one solution matches also I'm getting the document. Please correct me where I did the mistake.

Comment: Nested Document array solved my problem. Thank you.